# Convert Java array to Scala collection

Tags: java, scala

I would like to `map` over a Java array in Scala. For normal Java collections, I know I could use

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

new java.util.ArrayList[Int](1).asScala.map(_.toString)
```

However, for an array this conversion doesn't work:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales.asScala // doesn't compile
```

So how do I convert a Java array to a Scala collection or iterable or something I can map on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to import any implicit conversion for the `map` to be available over Java arrays. Try running the following in Scala shell:

```
java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales.map(_.toString)
```

The implicit conversion that allows the usage functions like `map` and `filter` over Java arrays comes with the `Predef`, which is imported implicitly.

As you mentioned in your own answer you can also explicitly convert an Array to another collection (which is possible thanks to the implicit conversion I mentioned previously).

Comment: Huh. I thought IntelliJ was telling me it didn't work. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

Aand I just found it:

```
Locale.getAvailableLocales.to[Seq]
```

No need for any implicit converters, or anything.